# how can we use flyway for cassandra, even when cassandra is not supported by flyway

Tags: cassandra, database-migration, flyway

I need to implement database migration scenario for a gradle and sbt application which uses cassandra.

if there is no any other way we can use flyway with cassandra, please suggest another tool which helps in maintaining versioning.

Answer (score 4):

This looks [tricky](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/823). A couple of alternative tools, inspired by Flyway, are mentioned in that issue that you could assess:

- https://github.com/patka/cassandra-migration
- https://github.com/Contrast-Security-OSS/cassandra-migration (discontinued, last change 2016)